# Angular5 Instascan - Open Camera Not Working <video>

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Angular5 - Instascan - Show Camera View (video tag) Not Working. But my camera is open.

---

app.component.ts

```
constructor(){    
this.Instascan= require('instascan'); 

let scanner = new this.Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById("preview") });

scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
  console.log(content);
});
this.Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
  if (cameras.length > 0) {
    scanner.start(cameras[0]);
  } else {
    console.error('No cameras found.');
  }
}).catch(function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});
}
```

app.component.html

```
<video id="preview"></video>
```

Instascan --- https://github.com/schmich/instascan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let scanner = new this.Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById("preview") });
```

The problem is that you're executing the above code in the constructor, when view has no been initialized yet. `document.getElementById("preview")` will return `null` because no elements are found at this moment. Hence, the thing you're trying to use it never correctly initialized.

You should run that code in Angular's `AfterViewInit` hook. Also, you should use `ViewChild` decorator to grab the `ElementRef` instead of using `document`. It's against good practice to access DOM like you're doing here.